# Volatile не работает

Tags: java, volatile

```
public class Tester{

    static volatile StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, Throwable {
        Tester t = new Tester();

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            es.execute(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sb.append("a");
                }

            });
        }
        es.shutdown();
        System.out.println(sb);

    }

}
```

Если volatile должно отключить кеширование, почему я после каждого запуска программы вижу разные результаты?

То "ааа", то "ааааа", то "аааа" или вообще "ааа а".

Comment: Какое кэширование, вы не дожидаетесь пока у вас потоки отработают до конца. Используете небезопасный в многопоточности StringBuilder. К тому же он вполне может быть локальной переменной в методе main.

Comment: мне кажется, вы забыли про synchronized

Comment: >Volatile не работает

20 лет работы над java идут прахом - гениальный отечественный программист нашел критичный баг в языке

Comment: ))) я в плане, что у меня не работает ))

Comment: Да ладно вам, заминусовали ни за что.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@romashechka](/users/17582/romashechka)](/users/17582/romashechka), то что вы объявили волатильным статическое поле `sb` скажется только на нем, а не на внутреннем состоянии объекта `StringBuilder`.

Если бы вы делали несколько присвоений вида `sb=...`, то модификатор `volatile` обеспечил бы видимость этих присвоений между потоками. Но вы вызываете `sb.append(...)`, меняющий **внутреннее** состояние объекта. А `StringBuilder`, как вам заметил [[@Mage](/users/4333/mage)](/users/4333/mage), не реализует потокобезопасность для своего внутреннего состояния. Так что надо делать `synchronized`.

Comment: Ну и поскольку это ваш не первый вопрос по многопоточности, традиционно порекомендую "книгу с поездом". Автор дотошно разжевывает все нюансы работы с потоками.

![BrianGoetz](http://i.imgur.com/4t6N0FT.jpg)

Comment: здесь тоже подчитал интерсного о volatile http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html